# 2008 Volkswagen Gti blower fan not working

Tags: vw, fan, gti

So I was tapping fuses for some rando crap and like an idiot sense I couldn’t find the fuse taker outer I tried using a flat head screwdriver boom popped a fuse, turned out it was for the blower moter I replaced that and now my fan doesn’t run at all, no speeds nothing and all anyone talks about is the resistor so I replaced that, and now I’m still stuck here freezing my ass off becuae my stupid fan wont work, I’ve checked every fuse under the sun! Please tell me someone knows what the f I did?????

Comment: The resistor is there to reduce fan power in the lower settings. If switched to max power, the resistor is bypassed. That means: If there is a problem with the resistor, one or more of the lower power settings will not work, but the max power setting will do. Since even that does not in your case, it was not the resistor.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Is this a manual three or four speed system controlled by a simple rotary switch or an infinitely adjustable fan blower (often automatically controlled)?  If manual, I’m thinking you blew the thermal limiter on the motor resistor block, inside the HVAC system.  Also, did you check ALL the fuses both inside the passenger compartment AND in the engine compartment?